# Why does my Ruby script slow down over time?

Tags: ruby, performance, file-io, class-method

I have a 2.6 gigabyte text file containing a dump of a database table, and I'm trying to pull it into a logical structure so the fields can all be uniqued.  The code I'm using to do this is here:

```
class Targetfile
  include Enumerable

  attr_accessor :inputfile, :headers, :input_array

  def initialize(file)
    @input_array = false
    @inputfile = File.open(file, 'r')
    @x = @inputfile.each.count
  end

  def get_headers
    @y = 1
    @inputfile.rewind
    @input_array = Array.new
    @headers = @inputfile.first.chomp.split(/\t/)
    @inputfile.each do |line|
      print "\n#{@y} / #{@x}"
      @y+=1
      self.assign_row(line)
    end
  end

  def assign_row(line)
    row_array = line.chomp.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace).split(/\t/)
    @input_array << Hash[ @headers.zip(row_array) ]
  end

  def send_build
    @input_array || self.get_headers
  end

  def each
    self.send_build.each {|row| yield row}
  end

end
```

The class is initialized successfully and I am left with a Targetfile class object.

The problem is that when I then call the `get_headers` method, which converts the file into an array of hashes, it begins slowing down immediately.

This isn't noticeable to my eyes until around item number 80,000, but then it becomes apparent that every 3-4,000 lines of the file, some sort of pause is occurring.  That pause, each time it occurs, takes slightly longer, until by the millionth line, it's taking longer than 30 seconds.

For practical purposes, I can just chop up the file to avoid this problem, then combine the resulting lists and unique -that- to get my final outputs.

From a curiosity standpoint, however, I'm unsatisfied.

Can anyone tell me why this pause is occurring, why it gets longer, and if there's any way to avoid it elegantly?  Really I just want to know what it is and why it happens, because now that I've noticed it, I see it in a lot of other Ruby scripts I run, both on this computer and on others.

Comment: Can you try this on a file with much smaller size ? It will help you identify if the issue is the code or the size of the file

Comment: Instead of `@x = @inputfile.each.count` use `@x = %x(wc -l path/to/file).to_i`. wc is very fast and made just for this.

Comment: Can you please monitor how much RAM ruby demands while running this script?

Comment: Maybe your system is low on memory and is starting to use the page file after you load enough lines? Check your process memory consumption.

Comment: ah.  Memory consumption creeps up constantly over the course of the script until it burns up all available memory and swap to boot.  the slow-down occurs before the computer's RAM is full, but it gets much worse after it fills.

Comment: The file is a dump from a database. Pulling it into another one seems redundant. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the infamous garbage collector -- Ruby's memory managment mechanism.

> Note: It's worth mentioning that Ruby, at least MRI, isn't a high performance language.

The garbage collector runs whenever memory starts to run out. The garbage collector pauses the execution of the program to deallocate any objects that can no longer be accessed. The garbage collector only runs when memory starts to run out. That's why you're seeing it periodically.

There's nothing you can do to avoid this, except write more memory efficiant code, or rewrite in a language that can has better/manual memory management.

Also, your OS may be paging. Do you have enough physical memory for this kind of task?

Comment: I suppose I must not.  Well, that's a shame.  I'll just have to break this sucker up into chunks for now and seek out a course in C/C++.

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MaxwellEvans: Sure. Ruby just isn't for serious data processing. How much mem do you have? What OS?

Comment: running Linux (ubuntu), 8 gigs of physical RAM

Comment: @MaxwellEvans: You have plenty of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest doing this in the DBM, not Ruby or any other language. A DBM can tell you the unique values for a field very quickly, especially if it's already indexed.

Trying to do this in any language is duplicating the basic functionality of the database in something designed for general computing.

Instead, use Ruby with an ORM like Sequel or Active Record, and issue queries to the database and let it return the things you want to know. Don't iterate over every row, that's madness, ask it to give you the unique values and go from there.

I wouldn't blame Ruby, because the same problem would occur in any other language given the same host and RAM. C/C++ might delay the inevitable by generating more compact code, but your development time will slow drastically, especially as you learn an unknown language like C. And the risk of unintended errors goes up because you have to do a lot more housekeeping and defensive programming than you'd do in Ruby, Python, or Perl.

Use each tool for what it's designed for and you'll be ahead.

Looking at your code, you could probably improve the chances of making it through a complete run by NOT trying to keep every row in memory. You said you're trying to determine uniqueness, so keep only the unique column values you're interested in, which you can do easily using Ruby's Set class. You can throw the values of each thing you want to determine uniqueness on, walk the file, and Set will only keep the unique values.

Comment: Databases manage large datasets quite well, that's what they're for.

Comment: (yeah, I ended up processing these by loading them into a mysql database and doing what you suggested.  I actually just came back onto stackoverflow intending to post "durp, wrong tool for the job to begin with.")

Comment: That happens, and is how we learn. We use Ruby for some heavyweight things that have amazed our management, because we can outrun very expensive software on dedicated hardware, when we're using small VM slices. It's all in grabbing the right tools and letting them do what they're good at.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the headers as keys for the hash. They are strings, and hashes duplicate string keys. That is a lot of unnecessary strings. Try if converting them to symbols speeds things up:

```
@headers = @headers.map{|header| header.to_sym}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Garbage Collector.  You can force garbage collection by putting in GC.start in your program.  Have it run periodically.
I had to do the same thing for a daemon I wrote.  It works well.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html